# How do you detect when an Add-on SDK panel has been shown?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

[The documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/panel.html#show) says:

> **show**
>
> This event is emitted when the panel is shown.

So in `main.js` I did this (where `thePanel` is using the `require("panel").Panel` method):

```
thePanel.port.on("show", function(d) {
    console.log('The panel has just been shown');
});
```

But the event doesn't seem to be called. I've also tried doing a function in the content script for `window.onfocus` but that doesn't appear to be called either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 sorts of events in the SDK:

- built-in events, defined in the SDK APIs
- user-defined events, which the add-on developer defines.

To ensure that if you define your own event called "show" it won't clash with the built-in "show", all user-defined events - and only user-defined events - are scoped inside the "port" property.

The "show" event you're listening to here is a built-in event, so you should not use "port" to listen for it. So the following code should do what you want:

```
var panel = require("panel").Panel({
});

panel.on("show", function() {
  console.log("panel is showing");
});

panel.show();
```